# UITableView and ASIHTTPRequest

Tags: uitableview, asihttprequest

How do I put a downloaded image into a cell?

I don't know how to put response data out when it loaded into `cell.imageView.image`.

Here is the code:

```
   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   ....
   ....
   NSURL *photoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:user.photo];
   ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:photoURL];
   [request setDownloadCache:[ASIDownloadCache sharedCache]];
   [request setDelegate:self];
   [request startAsynchronous];
   cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",user.first_name,user.last_name];
   cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

   //image loaded
   - (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
   {
      NSData *responseData = [request responseData];
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Here**](https://github.com/akosma/async-uitableview/) is a sample code to have a guide line and [**a brief description.**](http://kosmaczewski.net/2009/03/08/asynchronous-loading-of-images-in-a-uitableview/)

Comment: Yes, **FlickrCell** is a custom cell.